# DROP TABLE IF EXISTS vs OBJECT_ID IS NOT NULL

Tags: sql-server, performance

When I create a temporary table, I usually make sure that if they exist, I drop them.

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#tempTable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tempTable
```

I recently realized that the following method does the same:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tempTable
```

Is there one way better than the other ?

Comment: `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` seems a lot simpler and more intuitive / clear ....

Comment: I agree, but I've seen the first method being used more often than the second. It's the reason why I'm wondering if there is a performance reason associated or something else

Comment: Because the second has only been added to SQL Server recently

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Explanation**

They do the same thing just different syntax, and the later method in your question is newer. The `IF EXISTS` clause has been supported with `DROP TABLE` since **SQL Server 2016 13.x** up through the current version as of writting this, SQL Server 2019 (15.x).

**Documentation**

The `IF EXISTS` functionality is documented in the arguments section here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments